# Update the result in two equal fragments

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have to implement a game (tic-tac-toe) in which I have two fragments and in each fragment the tic-tac-toe grid. when I click on one it inserts "x" when I click on the other it inserts "o". The problem is that I don't know how to update the click in both. I created two classes, one for x and the other for o. in the main_layout I created the container for each fragment and use the same tic_layout for each of the two fragments. 
how can I update the result in both?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: I solved by implementing two interfaces

Comment: hard coupling between fragments is harder to maintain

Answer (score 0):

use activity for result to send a message back into a activity.
ou you can use LiveData

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying this way, but that's not what kind of message I send because for X and O I use a setText () of Button. should I memorize the boxes clicked in a different way?